# Cannot COPY NULL into INT (TIMESTAMP) column in Cassandra

Tags: csv, cassandra

I have a table in Cassandra (cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.5.0):

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tytandb.test1
>
> ( BS_CUSTOMER_ID  INT,
>
> CRM_CUSTOMER_ID   INT,
>
> ID    INT,
>
> PRIMARY KEY (BS_CUSTOMER_ID) );

And I have a CSV file:

> "BS_CUSTOMER_ID","CRM_CUSTOMER_ID","ID"
>
> "1179","4","4"
>
> "1226","122","122"
>
> "1237","161",""

And I am loading this file in CQLSH with this command:

> COPY TEST1 (BS_CUSTOMER_ID, CRM_CUSTOMER_ID, ID) FROM
> 't_customers_13.csv' WITH HEADER = 'true' AND DELIMITER = ',' AND
> QUOTE = '"' AND NULL = '';

And I am receiving this error message:

> Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - invalid literal for int() with
> base 10: '',  given up without retries

It is the 3rd value (NULL) in the last line that causes the error.

Why I cannot copy NULL (empty value) into an INT column? And what I can do to copy NULL into INT columns?

I have the same problem with TIMESTAMP columns.

With VARCHAR it's OK and I can copy NULL values into VARCHAR columns.

Any ideas?

Comment: For any `NULL` column values in your CSV, you might try simply omitting those column names from your CQL `INSERT` statement entirely.  When that particular row is then `SELECT` (using the column name whose value _wasn't_ added), you _should_ get a `NULL` value for that row column.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. But I cannot omit any column as almost all of them may contain NULLs in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a bug description in JIRA:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11549

And the patch worked for me both on Linux and Windows:

https://github.com/stef1927/cassandra/commit/6e7664380bb6ddea37efd5f866b7631fdc84bdac